# how to set general rule for mosquitto(eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15) users in acl? I tried several ways but never succeeded

Tags: mqtt, acl, mosquitto

I wanna know how to set general rules for all users?
I hope to let all user can subscribe topics start with **/c2d/xxx** and publish topics start with **/d2c/xxx**
ex: /c2d/config/get/0123456789A, /c2d/dashboard/info/0123456789A

this is my first version of acl,

```
# Give admin full access to everything
user admin
topic readwrite #
# Allow all users to read and write to specific topics
topic readwrite all users /c2d/#
topic readwrite all users /d2c/#
```

users except admin can't receive the topic start with **/c2d**, like: **/c2d/config/get/0123456789A**
after I read the document, I edit my acl file like this:

```
# Give admin full access to everything
user admin
topic readwrite #
# Allow all users to read and write to specific topics
#topic readwrite all users /c2d/#
#topic readwrite all users /d2c/#
pattern readwrite /c2d/#
pattern readwrite /d2c/#
```

but after I reload the config (docker kill --signal=HUP mqtt-container) I still can't receive topic start with **/c2d/xxx** by other user, please help QQ

this is my python code, to subscribe the message from topics, only when user is admin can receive messages like receive topic:/c2d/xxx

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payload_string = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
    payload_json = json.loads(payload_string)
    topic = msg.topic
    print(f"receive topic: {topic}")
    try:
        if topic == f'/c2d/info/{MAC}':
            payload = get_c2d_info_payload()
            client.publish(f"/d2c/info/{MAC}", json.dumps(payload))
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.username_pw_set(username='user2', password='xxxx')
        
        client.tls_set(ca_certs="./mqtt_ssl/ca.crt",
                       certfile="./mqtt_ssl/client.crt",
                       keyfile="./mqtt_ssl/client.key",
                       cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                       tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        client.tls_insecure_set(True)
        client.on_message = on_message
        client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, 60)
        print(f'EW50 {MAC} simulator started successfully.')
        # return_code是為了抓取loop被正常結束
        return_code = client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

> The first set of topics are applied to anonymous clients, assuming
> allow_anonymous is true. User specific topic ACLs are added after a
> user line as follows:
>
> ```
> user <username>
> ```

This means anything after a `user <username>` line is applied to that user. Order in the ACL file matters.

You should also look at using the `pattern` to create rules before defining rules for a specific user.

But for repair you are trying to do making use of a authentication/authorize plugin may be a better choice then you can generate ACL rules programmatically.

Comment: I tried to put general rule in front of admin rule(or delete admin rule), it's still not working, I'll survey using authentication/authorize plugin(to generate acl file?), thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I succeed with this following rule, without any user specific setting.

```
pattern readwrite /c2d/#
pattern readwrite /d2c/#
```

Comment: [The docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) indicate that it should not matter if this is after a user: "Pattern ACLs apply to all users even if the `user` keyword has previously been given".